# Type inference in Scala when passed a complex generic object

Tags: scala, generics

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to get type inference to work with my complex object type being passed in.  The objects outside of the scope of Test are out of my control.  Currently I have to specifically define the generics I am using (the Bar types).

```
trait Martini[A]

trait Foo[A <: Martini[A]] {
  def foo(): A
}

class Bar extends Martini[Bar] {
  def whoAmI = "Bar"
}

object Bar extends Foo[Bar] {
  override def foo(): Bar = new Bar()
}

object Test extends App {
  //    val bar: Bar = test(Bar) // Want to do this, but doesn't work
  val bar: Bar = test[Bar, Bar.type](Bar) // Works
  println(bar.whoAmI)

  def test[A <: Martini[A], F <: Foo[A]](f: F): A = {
    f.foo()
  }
}
```

The line I commented out is what I would like to achieve.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well... `variance` is important.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh No, for this question it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, there's no point introducing a type parameter like your `F` which is only used once as parameter type. It can be simplified to

```
def test[A <: Martini[A]](f: Foo[A]): A = {
  f.foo()
}
```

which will fix the type inference here as well.

Comment: Will it still work if `Foo` is contra-variant ? What is `default` behavior if we do not specify the `variance` of as `Foo[+A]` or `Foo[-A]` ?

Comment: Yes (of course, then `foo` and `test` will need different types because _this_ `Foo` can't be contravariant).